# Discovering their self and discovering themselves

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, possessives, reflexives, possessive-pronouns

In adolescence, teenagers discover their self. (as in the “self” with a possessive their)
OR
In adolescence, teenagers discover themselves (reflexive pronoun).

I think both are potentially acceptable. Any thoughts on either of these? Is there anything wrong  or do they both sound fine? Please give me some insight!

Comment: They are both grammatical. Are you asking a philosophical question here?

Comment: The self (noun) is the unique set of abstract characteristics that, at a given or implied time, comprise a sentient being - it is rarely used outside of philosophy, except in such phrases as, e.g. **his younger self would have acted otherwise." Themselves (pronoun) means "What they are like", "what their character is. "Themselves", in the context of "to discover oneself" is essentially vague and indefinite - it implies "finding out what one's strengths and weaknesses are", but can stretch beyond this to include proclivities.

Comment: It has more to do with word choice. Basically trying to find the correct phrase that means “ self-discovery”. I am not trying to ask a philosophical question; rather, I am trying to see which choice is better. Would it be weird to reference “the self” if this is just a comment on teenagers’ general lifestyle?